# How homeomorphic to an interval of $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb Z_2/\sim$?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory, quotient-spaces

Let $W_2\in\Bbb Z_2$ be any finite binary word as an element of the 2-adic integers.  Let the relation For all $W:$ $\overline{0}1W_2\sim\overline{1}0W_2$ be a quotient on $\Bbb Z_2$.

When we read the number backwards, this equivalence relation is the same one which sets equivalent binary representations of real numbers the same, e.g. $0.0\overline1=0.1\overline0$.  So it defines a quotient map on $\Bbb Z_2$ which gives me the real numbers in the unit interval, at least as a set, when read in reverse.

I'm trying to work out "how homeomorphic" the result $\Bbb Z_2/{\sim}$ is to the real interval.  On a prima facie basis it's very similar because it contains all the same elements and they will be close together if they differ by a small power of $2$ (if read as real numbers) or a large power of two if read as p-adic numbers.

But I can see a subtle difference insofar as the distance in the p-adic topology is only the first digit of difference whereas in the real topology, it is the sum of that plus all subsequent digits of difference.  I guess this is the essence of the padics being totally disconnected, while $\Bbb R$ is connected.  So my tentative (incompetent) topology skills say the map from $\Bbb Z_2/{\sim}\to\Bbb R$ is not a homeomorphism.

But the motivation I need to satisfy, is that I'd like to understand when a function which is continuous in $\Bbb Z_2/{\sim}$ is continuous in $\Bbb R$.  It looks to me like any arbitrary function which is continuous in $\Bbb Z/{\sim}$ will also be continuous in $\Bbb R$ despite the map not being a homeomorphism.  It looks to me like disconnectedness is only the property that doesn't push through from one to the other, but continuity is preserved. Is this intuit right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, your map is a homeomorphism.  $\mathbb Z_2$ is totally disconnected, but ${\mathbb Z_2 /} {\sim}$ is connected.

Comment: I don't understand $\overline{0}1W_2\sim\overline{1}0W_2$ nor why you don't try to make your stuff concrete instead of disgressing with abstract nonsense.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar that's a help. Do you have anything to add about the query about the two different metrics I allude to in paragraph $3$? That's the thing which made me doubt it. Does the 2-adic metric push through the quotient to become the standard metric on $\Bbb R$ as a quotient metric?  That seems doubtful.

Comment: @reuns $\overline01_2$ is the binary string $\ldots0001_2$ and $W_2$ is any finite binary string of your choosing and $\overline01W_2$ is one appended to the end of the other so if $W=1010_2$ then $\overline01W_2=\ldots00011010_2$. I'm sorry you don't understand why and I don't perceive that I do what you say. That may be a shortcoming on my part, but one which I will probably continue to struggle to avoid so I apologise in advance. I try to be as clear as I can and everything I have clarified in this comment I thought I already wrote in the original wording.

Comment: In what sense is it a quotient? You are sending $a=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n2^n\in \Bbb{Z}_2, a_n\in \{0,1\}$ to $f(a)=\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n 2^{-n}\in \Bbb{R}$ and identifying $a$ with $b$ if $f(a)=f(b)$ (note how concrete this is compared to your question) Then what?

Comment: @reuns do you agree that $\Bbb Z_2$ discriminates $\overline{0}1_2$ from $\overline{1}0_2$ while $\Bbb R$ does not discriminate $0.1\overline{0}$ from $0.0\overline{1}_2$?  Assuming you do, then you should be able to see that there is a quotient map from 2-adic integers to real numbers in the unit interval obtained by writing them in reverse and applying the equivalence relation on binary representations of real numbers which you are already very familiar with.

Comment: Quotient in what sense? Continuous and homeomorphic means you have a topology. So what is it (makes thing concretes, avoid abstract nonsense)

Comment: @reuns thank-you for taking an interest and trying to help me. The topologies on $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb R$ are the standard ones. One thing which I will accept is a little vague, is the question of what is the topology of the quotient $\Bbb Z_2/{\sim}$.  But to be fair to me, that is the matter into which the question inquires and if I knew that, I wouldn't be asking the question. The only way I know to combine a topology with a quotient to get a new topology is through the concept of the quotient topology so I assumed that is the topology.